# Set language for mat-datepicker globally

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-translate

I need to set the language for all datepickers in the application when clicking on the corresponding button in another component, example given in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization) works only in a particular component and I have datepickers in many places so I would not like to add the same logic to each component. Is there any way to do it?

topbar.component.html

```
  <button (click)="changeLanguage('fr')" class="topbar__languageButton" mat-button></button>
  <button (click)="changeLanguage('en')" class="topbar__languageButton" mat-button></button>
```

topbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-topbar',
    templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.scss'],
})
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    changeLanguage(language: string): void {
        this.adapter.setLocale(language);
    }
}
```

target.component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

target.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-target',
    templateUrl: './target.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./target.component.scss'],
})
export class TargetComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though in their example, the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` injection token and also the `DateAdapter` are provided at the component level, this does not stop you from having these provided by your root injector in `AppModule`. By providing them there, all your components will be getting the same locale settings, unless overriden in another module.

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de-CH' },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```